# keyboard ввод данных при русской раскладке

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, hotkeys, keyboardhook

Мне необходимо на выходе функции отправлять данные о нажатой кнопке только в латинице. Проблема в том, что библиотека keyboard считывает нажатие на клавиатуру при любой раскладке и выдает символы в той раскладке, которая стоит у пользователя. Можно как то, чтобы при нажатии на клавиатуру на русской раскладке, скажем на кнопку с русской буквой "И" конвертировала в латинскую букву "B" этой же кнопки.

```
text = keyboard.read_hotkey()
```

Comment: В моём случае (Debian) `keyboard.read_key()` выдавала латинскую букву при любой раскладке. Какая у Вас система? И точно нужно именно `read_hotkey()`?

Comment: @Андрей, у меня windows 10, мне необходимо, чтобы считывались и горячие клавиши и просто символы c клавиатуры, посмотрев в документации я нашел лишь этот вариант(read_hotkey) хорошо подходящий для этой задачи.

Comment: Попробуйте `keyboard.read_hotkey(suppress = False)`

Comment: Не знаю, у меня что в Линуксе, что в Винде выдаёт латиницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция возвращающая текущую раскладку

```
import ctypes
def get_language() -> str:
    """
    Данная функция проверяет раскладку клавиатуры
    :return: 'ru'/'en'
    """
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'
```